# Save data from HTML form into .CSV filve using PHP

Tags: php, html, forms, csv

I'm struggling a bit with obtaining data from my form and saving it to CSV file via PHP. This code is not working and I run out of ideas how to fix it. Is there anything wrong with the way I save it to CSV file? I'd be grateful for your help.

The code is supposed to work this way: I want the user to input some data to HTML form. Then with the usage of AJAX and PHP I want to save it to a csv file. The saving doesn't work - the file stays empty.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

<h2>AJAX</h2>
<script>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    //collect form data
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    //check name is set
    if($name ==''){
        $error[] = 'Name is required';
    }

    //check for a valid email address
    if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
         $error[] = 'Please enter a valid email address';
    }

    //if no errors carry on
    if(!isset($error)){

        # Title of the CSV
        $Content = "Name, Email\n";

        //set the data of the CSV
        $Content .= "$name, $email\n";

        # set the file name and create CSV file
        $FileName = "sth.txt"//"formdata-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
       // header('Content-Type: application/csv'); 
      //  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $FileName . '"'); 
        echo $Content;
        exit();
    }
}

//if their are errors display them
if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
        echo "<p style='color:#ff0000'>$error</p>";
    }
}
?> 
</script>
<form action='' method='post'>
<p><label>Name</label><br><input type='text' name='name' value=''></p> 
<p><label>Email</label><br><input type='text' name='email' value=''></p> 
<p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'></p> 
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by it is not working? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: This `$FileName = "sth.txt"//"formdata-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";` should be throwing you a parse error and not idea why you have all that PHP wrapped inside script tags. Plus, you're not even writing anything.

Comment: Where is the actual code for saving to .csv file?

Comment: It was supposed to write with echo $content. How do I write to file differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've commented `;` character

Change:

```
$FileName = "sth.txt"//"formdata-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
```

To:

```
$FileName = "sth.txt";//"formdata-".date("d-m-y-h:i:s").".csv";
```

Also I don't see where You save data to file.

So use this example:

```
$FileName = "sth.txt";
file_put_contents($FileName, $Content);
```

Comment: I've changed code to http://wklej.org/id/2304785/ but unfortunately the data I write in form is still not daved in the sth.txt file. Any other ideas?